# Windows 8 Metro App Making a settings flyout

Tags: c#, xaml

I am making a game where i want the users to be able to swipe from the right and open the settings from the charm bar in windows 8.
I have tried many things, but i haven't managed to make it work. If someone has done it, please tell me how you did it. I am using Visual studio 2012 express.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you post the code have tried?

Answer (score 13):

Update:

From Windows 8.1 and onwards a SettingsFlyout control has been added to the control collection in Windows Store App.

Add => New => SettingsFlyout

[image]

Then add it like so:

```
sealed partial class App
{

    public App()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Suspending += OnSuspending;
    }

    protected override void OnWindowCreated(WindowCreatedEventArgs args)
    {
        SettingsPane.GetForCurrentView().CommandsRequested += OnCommandsRequested;
    }

    private void OnCommandsRequested(SettingsPane sender, SettingsPaneCommandsRequestedEventArgs args)
    {
        var setting = new SettingsCommand("MySetting", "MySetting", handler =>
            new MySettingsFlyout().Show());
        args.Request.ApplicationCommands.Add(setting);
    }
```

Result:

[image]
[image]
**Old way of doing it:**

Here is how you do it with xaml and c# in Windows 8

1.Create a xaml usercontrol

```
 <UserControl
    x:Class="CSharp_Settings.Settings.Help_Settings"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="646">
    <Border BorderBrush="#FF590151" BorderThickness="1">
        <Grid Background="White" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid Background="#FFFF00F2" Grid.Row="0">
                <Grid Margin="40,20,17,13">
                    <Grid.Transitions>
                        <TransitionCollection>
                            <EntranceThemeTransition FromHorizontalOffset="50" />
                        </TransitionCollection>
                    </Grid.Transitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Button Click="Button_Click_1" Margin="0,3,0,0" Grid.Column="0"

HorizontalAlignment="Left" Style="{StaticResource BackButtonStyle}"/>
                    <TextBlock Margin="10,5,0,0" Grid.Column="1" FontFamily="Segoe UI"

FontWeight="SemiLight" FontSize="24.6667" Text="Help" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                    <Image Source="/Assets/icon.png" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="2"

Margin="0,0,6,0" />
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
            <Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="40,24,23,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <Grid.Transitions>
                    <TransitionCollection>
                        <EntranceThemeTransition FromHorizontalOffset="120" />
                    </TransitionCollection>
                </Grid.Transitions>
                <TextBlock Text="Something" Foreground="Black"/>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

codebehind for usercontrol

```
using Windows.UI.ApplicationSettings;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
namespace CSharp_Settings.Settings
{
    public sealed partial class Help_Settings 
    {
        public Help_Settings()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Parent is Popup)
                ((Popup)Parent).IsOpen = false;
            SettingsPane.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Registering the settings pane in the app

```
using CSharp_Settings.Settings;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.UI.ApplicationSettings;
using Windows.UI.Core;
using Windows.UI.Popups;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;

namespace CSharp_Settings
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _window = Window.Current.Bounds;
            Window.Current.SizeChanged += OnWindowSizeChanged;
            SettingsPane.GetForCurrentView().CommandsRequested += CommandsRequested;
        }

        private Rect _window;
        private Popup _popUp;
        private const double WIDTH = 646;

        private void OnWindowSizeChanged(object sender, WindowSizeChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            _window = Window.Current.Bounds;
        }

        private void CommandsRequested(SettingsPane sender, SettingsPaneCommandsRequestedEventArgs args)
        {
            args.Request.ApplicationCommands.Add(new SettingsCommand("help", "Help", Handler));
        }

        private void Handler(IUICommand command)
        {
            _popUp = new Popup
                         {
                             Width = WIDTH,
                             Height = _window.Height,
                             IsLightDismissEnabled = true,
                             IsOpen = true
                         };
            _popUp.Closed += OnPopupClosed;
            Window.Current.Activated += OnWindowActivated;
            _popUp.Child = new Help_Settings {Width = WIDTH, Height = _window.Height};
            _popUp.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, SettingsPane.Edge == SettingsEdgeLocation.Right ? (_window.Width - WIDTH) : 0);
            _popUp.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, 0);
        }

        private void OnWindowActivated(object sender, WindowActivatedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.WindowActivationState == CoreWindowActivationState.Deactivated)
                _popUp.IsOpen = false;
        }

        private void OnPopupClosed(object sender, object e)
        {
            Window.Current.Activated -= OnWindowActivated;
        }
    }
}
```

And in Javascript and html you do create in html:

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
<body>
    <div style="border: 1px solid #AB00A5" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.SettingsFlyout" data-win-options="{settingsCommandId:'help', width:'narrow'}">
        <div class="win-ui-dark win-header" style="background-color:#FF00F7">
            <button type="button" onclick="WinJS.UI.SettingsFlyout.show()" class="win-backbutton"></button> 
            <div class="win-label"> Help</div>
            <img src="../images/icon.png" style="position: absolute; right: 40px; width:35px; height:35px"/>
        </div>
        <div class="win-content win-settings-section">
            <h3>Help!</h3>
            <p> No help for you muahahaha</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

Function to register the settings pane:

    (function () {
    "use strict";
    WinJS.Application.onsettings = function (e) {
        e.detail.applicationcommands = {
            "about": {
                title: "About",
                href: "/html/settings_about.html"
            },
            "help": {
                title: "Help",
                href: "/html/settings_help.html"
            }
        };
        WinJS.UI.SettingsFlyout.populateSettings(e);
    };

    WinJS.Application.start();
})();
```

Keep in mind the following things:

- Use one word labels for the entry points

  - Max 4 entry points is   recommended
  - Narrow = 346 pixels
  - Wide =   646 pixels.
  - Height same    as the screen.
  - Header : backbutton +  name of entry point + app icon, background color same as app tile
  - Settingspanel border color should be 20% darker than header color,    background should be white.
  - Scrolling OK but max twice the height
  - No buttons for navigation,   commands or commit changes
  - No direct actions if entry   point is   clicked   Permission command is system-controlled
  - Should be a  flyout with entrance animation
  - Lightly dismissible  Should be on same side as settings (use SettingsEdgeLocation property)

Comment: To format blocks of code, indent each line by 4 spaces (in addition to whatever indentation it already had). (When copy/pasting, the easiest option is to select all the code, and click the `{}` button in the editor). For bullet lists, just start each line with a plain minus sign. Hope that helps in the future. :)

Comment: jalf, that is exactly what I did and this is the result :(

Comment: I can see at least a few lines that aren't indented,and the bullet point lines start with a fancy • instead of `-`, so you missed some, at least :) I tried to edit it, but someone else were already doing so, so I figured it'd be simpler and easier to bring it up here :)

Comment: I really wish SO will support gists in the future for formatting.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help all, I got to start getting this right :)

Comment: I want the listeners in the user control to make changes to mainPage, how do i that?

Comment: Your first question has been answered, mark an answer and ask a new question but not as a comment as that is a completely new question. This is so others can also benefit from the questions and answers on this forum, and you will probably get more answers as well. You might also want to explain what listeners are and what kind of changes you want to make, and what you have tried so far. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need SettingsPane class

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.applicationsettings.settingspane.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The best way is probably to use the helper class from Callisto.